# finish() not called properly

Tags: android, android-activity

i have the following activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        String myString;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(arg0);
            setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)

            getData(bundle);
            doSmoethingWithMyString();
        }

        void getData(Bundle bundle) {
                if(bundle != null) {
                     myString = bundle.getString("myString")
                } else {
                    myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("myString")
                }

                if(myString == null)
                    finish();
        }

        void doSomethingWithMyString() {
                // here the string should be used
        }

}
```

If myString is null, finish() should be executed and close the activity. But although finish() is called, doSomethingWithMyString() seems to be executed after that and raises a NullPointerException. If i comment doSomethingWithMyString() out, the activity is closed properly.

Any Idea whats wrong?

Comment: I don't see where `doSomethingWithMyString()` is called at all.

Comment: @trojanfoe Most probably it is in `onDestroy()` or `setBaseData()`. `finish()` may not actually stop the activity right away.

Comment: doSomethingWithMyString() is setBaseData() :) copy and paste error..

@iccthedral: isnt there a way to let the activity close right when activity is finished withoutexecuting any code afterwards? Solving this with try{}catch{} blocks seems to be not the best way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem. See my comment as to why this works.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)

        getData(bundle);
        if(!isFinishing()) {
         doSmoethingWithMyString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

finish() will not close your activity immediately. Closing sequence will be initiated only when the control  is returned to Android framework. So all your remaining code in onCreate will be executed for sure